# Display Gender enum in ng-select in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

Not display Male , Female in ng-select in ui in angular v.16

```
export enum Gender
{
  Male,Female
}
```

**typescript**

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({providedIn: 'root',})
export class EnumService {
  displayAllEnums(enums: any[]) {
    const allEnums = {};
    enums.forEach((enumObject) => {
      const enumValues = {};
      for (const key in enumObject) {
        if (enumObject.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
          enumValues[key] = enumObject[key];
        }
      }
      allEnums[enumObject.constructor.name] = enumValues;
    });
    return allEnums;
  }
}
```

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {EnumService} from './enum.service';
import {Gender} from './gender.enum';

@Component({selector: 'app-enum-display', templateUrl: './enum-display.component.html',})
export class EnumDisplayComponent {
  allEnums: any;

  constructor(private enumService: EnumService) {
    this.allEnums = this.enumService.displayAllEnums([Gender]);
  }
}
```

Comment: And what is your question...?